# Listen to the World Cup

Tags: riddle

> 1. My first is a king
> 2. My second is energy
> 3. My third is a god
>
> Who am I?

**Hint 1**:

> I can dodge horses

**Hint 2** :

> I have lent my voice to the world cup, multiple times

Comment: Is it a thing or a person ?

Comment: @Nappa it's a person

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> Shakira

My first is a king

> Shah (a title given to the emperors, kings, princes and lords of Iran)

My second is energy

> Ki (or Qi)

My third is a god

> Ra (Egyptian god)

Hint 1:

> See her clip

Comment: I'm sure that's the intended answer, but the first part doesn't work either visually or audibly.

Comment: In my language it does audibly and in English it seems to fit too

Comment: @guillau4 well done :D

Comment: In English the king has vowel /ɑː/ but the answer has /æ/

Comment: @PeterTaylor Shakira is a spanish name so which pronunciation are you even considering? American? Spanish? English (UK)?

Comment: Well done. I was trying to fit in Gabriel Fernando Jesus somehow.

Comment: I was considering the English pronunciation, because the riddle is in English and I don't think I've ever heard a native English speaker try to use Spanish vowels. But if we want to consider the Spanish pronunciation it's /a/ so it still isn't the same.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Stop being picky for nothing. There is no dictionary saying how Shakira should be pronounced in English. Shah is close enough anyway to the way it sounds according to you. And the difference of pronunciation would never be the reason for not finding the answer.